# How to reduce memory consumption (RAM) on Python/Django project?

Tags: python, django, memory-management, memory-leaks, gunicorn

My memory usage on a Django DRF API project increases over time and RAM is getting filled once I reach 50+ API calls.

So far I tried

- loaded all models, class variable upfront
- used [memory profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/), cleaned code as possible to reduce variable usage
- added [garbage collection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html) : gc.disable() at beginning and gc.enable() at end of code
- added [ctypes](https://www.softwareatscale.dev/p/run-python-servers-more-efficiently) malloc.trim() at end of code etc
- setting [gunicorn](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#max-requests) max-requests limit ( this results in more model loading / response time at that moment)

Any suggestions on how to free up memory at the end of each request ?

Comment: The garbage collector will only remove data from memory if there are no references to that data. Make sure you really need to reduce your consumption as it is likely that the memory will return to the system if it needs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way that the CPython interpreter manages memory, it very rarely actually frees any allocated memory. Generally CPython processes will keep growing and growing in memory usage

Since you are using Gunicorn you can set the [`max_requests`](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#max-requests) setting which will regularly restart your workers and alleviate some "memory leak" issues

Comment: thanks, but once max_requests limit is reached this results in service down time / model re-loading.

Comment: @Sreejithc321 If you have enough workers then workers reloading shouldn't be an issue since there will be others to pick up the slack. How long does your app take to load and why does it take any significant amount of time?

Comment: there are 4 workers, ML based models are loaded upfront and loading time is ~5 min.

Comment: @Sreejithc321 okay wow, that is a long time for an API server to start. Does any actual calculation/processing happen in the Django process? If not then it may be worth dumping the results to a DB and serving the API from there?

Comment: Yeah certain image/text processing are done on api calls and results are given back. Also this need to be served in realtime.

Comment: I also have this issue even I set --max-requests=1000 --max-requests-jitter=30 in gunicorn. What is a good way to free memory beside restarting?